# Storing sessions with express-session, connect-mongo, and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

I am looking for guidance on setting up session based authentication with with Express-Session, connect-mongo, and Mongoose. Currently it's just generating a new UUID with every request and not saving anything to the sessions collection. Am I missing something obvious?

index.js

```
const mongoose = require("./db/connection");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors')
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const app = express();
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

//Register .env file
require('dotenv').config()


//Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({
  genid: (req) => {
    return uuidv4()
  },
  secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 },
  store: MongoStore.create({
    client: mongoose.connection.getClient(),
    dbName: process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME,
    collectionName: "sessions",
    stringify: false,
    autoRemove: "interval",
    autoRemoveInterval: 1
    })
  }) 
);
```

connection.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv').config()

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://devroot:devroot@localhost:27017/${process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME}?authSource=admin`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true
});


mongoose.connection
  .on("open", () => console.log("The goose is open"))
  .on("close", () => console.log("The goose is closed"))
  .on("error", (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit();
  })

module.exports = mongoose;
```

Comment: Which version of `express`, `express-session` & `connect-mongo` are you using?

Comment: "express": "^4.17.1",
"connect-mongo": "^4.5.0",
"express-session": "^1.17.2",
"mongoose": "^5.13.7",

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setting [`saveUninitialized: false`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#saveuninitialized) means that a session is established only if it contains some information, that is, if a statement like `req.session.attribute = "value"` is executed during request processing. If that does not happen, the session is not stored, and also no session cookie issued, so that the next request triggers a new session (with a new UUID), but which may again not be stored.

The author probably "solved" the issue by setting `saveUninitialized: true`, but this has the following consequences:

- Every visitor to the website creates a new session entry (without any information in it) in the database even if they never interact with the site nor log on.
- Every visitor gets a session cookie in their browser even before actually logging on.

I consider both these consequences undesirable and would therefore prefer `saveUninitialized: false` so that sessions without information are effectively not created.

Answer (score 0):

Posting for visibility; this was related to:

```
saveUninitialized: false
```

Changing this to true forces save to the store.