# How do i create session without login in node js

Tags: node.js, express, session

I have seen lot of pdf to docx and similar conversion site working without login and provide output based on the visitor input at that specific session without asking login.

How does that works.

i tried similar things with a simple todo list app created using node.js. But the input i entered the very first time, showsup in every other browser when i try to access.

I have created a basic todolist app. when i access through the browser and add todo list, it is added in array and displayed back in the website.

But, after closing the browser and opening the IP from different brwoser, the old list present in the array still in use and shows up in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need a module like [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) that stores session information on the server and associates each session with a cookie that it sends to the browser. With that, every browser has its own cookie and hence its own session, so the input will no longer show up on all browsers.

You could establish a session without prior login, but I consider this problematic from a data privacy standpoint, see [Cookie Consent Logic Following GDPR guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69694635/cookie-consent-logic-following-gdpr-guidelines) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71980883/16462950.