# Deployment of a server with code that takes a 0.5-2 seconds to respond

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-services, web-deployment, chess

So I built a chess project for the sake of learning and the architecture that I choose was having a
1.client as a react app with all of the ui
2.a server as an express nodeJS
3.a third service which is a complex algorithm that can play chess.

The algorithm of the third service is quite heavy and takes 0.5-2 seconds of wait time for it to give response to the player.

As I deployed my project I noticed that when a player is playing against the algorithm he sends a request for the algorithm to play, and while he wait 0.5-2.0 seconds for response if another player is sending a request it breaks the previous request and only calculate the new request

So my question is what is the best way to deploy such a project so requests won’t interfere with each other?

So I tried playing against my algorithm in two different computers and noticed the first game is breaking when another game is played

(I’m using socket for the algorithm to talk to the client)

EDIT: should I just run the algo locally on every client machine instead of trying to have service respond to multiply clients?

Comment: can you provide more information about  chess algo service ? seems like you need some sort of "lock/mutex" but I don't understand why.

Comment: So every time a client is playing his turn he sends a req to the service with the updated game, and the algo is playing his turn and sends the updated game to the client.

Comment: So you probably to keep a separate state for each game. But it's hard to help without seeing a single line of code ...

Answer (score 0):

If the chess algorithm is *stateless*, different requests should not interfere with each other. Stateless means that

- the request contains the complete state of the board and which side is to move next
- the response contains the next move as determined by the algorithm.

Note that the state of the board comprises not only the position of the pieces, but also

- whether a pawn has just moved two squares ahead (needed for the "en passant" rule)
- whether a king or rook has already moved (needed for the "castling" rule).

Does your chess algorithm work that way? Or must it store information about each game *between moves* in order to compute the next move? That would be a *stateful* algorithm, and that requires you to have a session with the server, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74235950/how-do-i-create-session-without-login-in-node-js).